# Proguard ParseException: "Expecting keyword 'allowshrinking', 'allowoptimization', or 'allowobfuscation' before 'includedescriptorclasses"' on -Keep

Tags: android, proguard

Weird error that only pops up when running the Proguard step from Android Studio

The error:

`org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting keyword 'allowshrinking', 'allowoptimization', or 'allowobfuscation' before 'includedescriptorclasses' in line 42 of file...`

Here is the line in question in my Proguard file:

`-keep, includedescriptorclasses public class com.Foo.Bar {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
    public protected *;
}`

Noting that:

`-keep,allowobfuscations, allowoptimizations, allowshrinking, includedescriptorclasses public class com.Foo.Bar {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
    public protected *;
}`

Or any combination of keep modifiers still results in the same error message.

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: Its in the title, but I added it to the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option `includedescriptorclasses` is new in ProGuard 5.0. You are probably using an older version. The versions are all backward compatible, so you can just change the ProGuard jar.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio to do this. Running it right from the jar works fine, but not in the newest AS.

Comment: If you can't use the most recent version because Android Studio and Gradle link to an older version, you'll have to do without `includedescriptorclasses`. The option is only intended to make configuration of native code more convenient.

Comment: Yeah, I end up just proguarding elsewhere. Thanks!